# how do I show image after uploading it via delayed job in th api?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, react-native, delayed-job

I have a rails API for handling my react-native backend requests, the image is being uploaded there with Delayed job, so I am getting a default image on a successful profile picture update at first. The user data is fetched in the redux store after the app start, on restart the app I'm able to see the image. 
What do I do so that I don't have to restart my app?

Comment: Polling or WebSockets.

Comment: ok that's a nice way